# How to use jquery in IE9?

Tags: jquery, html

Does anyone know why this doesn't work in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/S7ERu/1/

```
//jquery
$("#submitpost").on("click", function () {
        alert('test');
});


//html
<a href="#" id="submitpost">Submit</a>
```

Full stand alone version, which does not work in IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submitpost").on("click", function () {
        alert('test');
        });
</script>
<a href="#" id="submitpost">Submit</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Does it not work ONLY in IE9? Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: LOL hope your IE is script enabled? Tools > options > Advanced! `:)`

Comment: Maybe a jsFiddle issue. Try [changing jQuery from 1.10.1 to 1.9.1](http://jsfiddle.net/S7ERu/4/). That worked for me.

Comment: Yes - this is strictly related to IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your new standalone sample, you're missing the final `});` to close out your `$(document).ready(function(){`.

I added that, and in IE9 it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, at least within JSFiddle, jQuery 1.10.1 in IE 9 throws a security error with:

```
1513: if ( parent && parent.frameElement ) {
```

```
Error: Access is denied.
```

This may be due to the site's use of multiple domains/origins to isolate fiddles via the same-origin policy.

You might try upgrading to 1.10.2. Since JSFiddle doesn't currently list it as an option, you can select "No-Library" and just include it in the markup:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ppzpn/).

Comment: Try the full version I just posted.

Comment: @4thSpace It seems to just be missing a `});` for the `.ready(function () {`.

Answer (score -1):

Bind after document is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {
//code here
});
</script>
```

Also make sure, if you are using the 1.10.2 that it is properly loaded from cache.

Comment: Downvoters: please explain your votes. It just might be helpful.